# Как после нажатия кнопки выполнять функция и ее результат передать в HTML (DJANGO)

Tags: python, html, django

у меня есть класс. В нем прописаны методы, которые возвращают значения. На данный момент функции срабатывают при загрузке странички и информация автоматически отображается на сайте. Мне нужно, чтобы загружалась страничка с 1 кнопкой или ссылкой. При нажатии на нее, только тогда срабатывали функции и отображалась информация. Я только разбираюсь с Django, не имею понятия как это реализовать.

HTML

```
<body>
    <span>TOKEN: {{ token }}</span>
    <span>ORGANISATION INFO: {{ orgInfo }}</span>
    <span>NOMENCLATURE: {{ nomencl }}</span>
</body>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    Iico = IicoRequest()
    data = {
        'token':Iico.getToken(),
        'orgInfo': Iico.getOrgInfo(),
        'nomencl': Iico.getNomenclature() }

    return render(request,'index.html', context=data)
```

как я могу это сделать ?

Comment: Как насчет javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
    <a href='?func=token'>show token</a>
    <span>TOKEN: {{ token }}</span>
    <span>ORGANISATION INFO: {{ orgInfo }}</span>
    <span>NOMENCLATURE: {{ nomencl }}</span>
</body>

views.py

def index(request):
    Iico = IicoRequest()
    funcs = {
        'token': Iico.getToken,
        ...
    }

    data = {}
    if 'func' in request.GET:
        fname = request.GET['func']
        if fname in funcs:
            data[fname] = funcs[fname]()
    return render(request,'index.html', context=data)
```

Думам, понятно, что зачем и почему. Будут вопросы - отвечу